# My useContext "isLoggedIn" variable is not updating after I navigate to another page after setIsLoggedIn(true)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a react context variable called "isLoggedIn" in a file called 'AuthContext.js', which I wrap my App.js with. This isLoggedIn variable tracks if a user is logged in to dynamically render a navigation bar and various pages. Here is my AuthContext.js file and my App.js which is wrapped with AuthProvider:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  // You can use useEffect to check the user's session 
  useEffect(() => {
    // Send a request to the /update1 
    //In summary, sending an empty request body with an empty Create1Dto object to
    // your /update1 endpoint should not cause any changes to the existing data in the user's profile.
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/auth/isloggedin', {}, { withCredentials: true })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          // Profile updated successfully, user is logged in
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          // Handle other response statuses
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 400 && error.response.data === 'User not found') {
          // User is not logged in or not authorized
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        } else {
          // Handle other errors
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
      });
  }, [isLoggedIn]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

and I wrapped my app with AuthProvider:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import MyProfile from './MyProfile';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import ProfileCreation from './ProfileCreation'; 
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import MainPage from './MainPage';
import QuizPage from './QuizPage';
import '../App.css'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AnimatePresence} from 'framer-motion';
import ResultsQuiz from './ResultsQuiz';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import Create1 from './Create1';
import Create2 from './Create2';
import Create3 from './Create3';
import { AuthProvider } from '../components/AuthContext';
import { ProfileProvider } from '../components/ProfileContext';
import { ImageUploadProvider } from '../components/ImageUploadContext';
import LogoutPage from './LogoutPage';
import MyPersonalProfile from './MyPersonalProfile';

function AppContent() {
    const location = useLocation();

    const { isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

   //Use the isAuthenticated state to conditionally render components based on the user's authentication status.


    const MainContainer = styled(Box)({
        minWidth: '80rem', // or your desired value
        minHeight: '45rem', // or your desired value
        overflow: 'auto'
      });
      
      const questions = [
        { id: 1, text: "I am the life of the party." },
        { id: 2, text: "I feel little concern for others." },
        { id: 3, text: "I am always prepared." },
        { id: 4, text: "I get stressed out easily." },
        { id: 5, text: "I have a rich vocabulary." },
        { id: 6, text: "I don't talk a lot." },
        { id: 7, text: "I am interested in people." },
        { id: 8, text: "I leave my belongings around." },
        { id: 9, text: "I am relaxed most of the time." },
        { id: 10, text: "I have difficulty understanding abstract ideas." },
        { id: 11, text: "I feel comfortable around people." },
        { id: 12, text: "I insult people." },
        { id: 13, text: "I pay attention to details." },
        { id: 14, text: "I worry about things." },
        { id: 15, text: "I have a vivid imagination." },
        { id: 16, text: "I keep in the background." },
        { id: 17, text: "I sympathize with others' feelings." },
        { id: 18, text: "I make a mess of things." },
        { id: 19, text: "I seldom feel blue." },
        { id: 20, text: "I am not interested in abstract ideas." },
        { id: 21, text: "I start conversations." },
        { id: 22, text: "I am not interested in other people's problems." },
        { id: 23, text: "I get chores done right away." },
        { id: 24, text: "I am easily disturbed." },
        { id: 25, text: "I have excellent ideas." },
        { id: 26, text: "I have little to say." },
        { id: 27, text: "I have a soft heart." },
        { id: 28, text: "I often forget to put things back in their proper place." },
        { id: 29, text: "I get upset easily." },
        { id: 30, text: "I do not have a good imagination." },
        { id: 31, text: "I talk to a lot of different people at parties." },
        { id: 32, text: "I am not really interested in others." },
        { id: 33, text: "I like order." },
        { id: 34, text: "I change my mood a lot." },
        { id: 35, text: "I am quick to understand things." },
        { id: 36, text: "I don't like to draw attention to myself." },
        { id: 37, text: "I take time out for others." },
        { id: 38, text: "I shirk my duties." },
        { id: 39, text: "I have frequent mood swings." },
        { id: 40, text: "I use difficult words." },
        { id: 41, text: "I don't mind being the center of attention." },
        { id: 42, text: "I feel others' emotions." },
        { id: 43, text: "I follow a schedule." },
        { id: 44, text: "I get irritated easily." },
        { id: 45, text: "I spend time reflecting on things." },
        { id: 46, text: "I am quiet around strangers." },
        { id: 47, text: "I make people feel at ease." },
        { id: 48, text: "I am exacting in my work." },
        { id: 49, text: "I often feel blue." },
        { id: 50, text: "I am full of ideas." }
    ];
    

    return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <MainContainer>
      <AuthProvider>
        <ProfileProvider>
            <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
              <Route path="/myprofile" element={<MyPersonalProfile />} />
              <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
              <Route path="/create" element={<ProfileCreation />} />
              <Route path = "/create/1" element ={<Create1 />} />
              <Route path = "/create/2" element ={<Create2 />} />
              <Route path = "/create/3" element ={<Create3 />} />
              <Route path="/quiz/:questionId" element={<QuizPage questions={questions}/> }  />
                <Route path="/resultsquiz" element={<ResultsQuiz />}/>
                <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
                <Route path="/logout" element={<LogoutPage />} />
            </Routes>
            </ProfileProvider>
            </AuthProvider>
      </MainContainer>
      </AnimatePresence>
    );
  }
  

  export default AppContent;
```

In my LoginPage, which is a sibling component of MainPage in the react router, I update isLoggedIn to 'true' after successful login and then use 'Navigate' to navigate back to the main page. But when I am on the main page, when I console.log "isLoggedIn", it shows up as false and the conditional rendering for the navbar is incorrect. I don't understand why my isLoggedIn state from my context is not updating. Here is my code for LoginPage.js and my code for MainPage.js.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import RightBox from '../components/RightBox.js';
import CreateNavbar from '../components/CreateNavbar.js';
import LeftBox from '../components/LeftBox.js'
import { Typography } from "@mui/material"; 
import InputField from '../components/InputFIeld.js';
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';
import { useTheme } from '@emotion/react';
import {Button} from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SelectError from '../components/SelectError.js';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { login, logout } from '../redux/authSlice.js'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm.js';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import LogButton from '../components/LogButton.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useAuth } from '../components/AuthContext.js';
import SelectSuccess from '../components/SelectSuccess.js';
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainNavbar from '../components/MainNavbar.js';
import PasswordInputField from '../components/PasswordInputField.js';
import { useProfile } from '../components/ProfileContext.js';


const FullPageCenter = styled('div')({
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  minHeight: '100vh', // Set the minimum height to 100% of the viewport height
});

//this is to center the content

const ItalicText = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  fontFamily: theme.typography.h1.fontFamily,
  fontStyle: 'italic',
  fontSize: '8rem',
  color: theme.palette.accent.main,  // Accessing the accent.main color
  // other styles for your component
  lineHeight: '0.9',
}));


const Wrapper = styled('div')({
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '45rem',
    width: '80rem',
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    marginBottom: '4rem',
    position: 'relative', // This is important for the absolute positioning of the child.
});
//this is to prevent resizing....


//does putting position of top level copmonent as relative make all the child components, including grandchildren components, relative to the top level component? 

//this is relative position only deals with direct children that are absolutely positioned

//wrapper is outermost container...centers stuff in scree horizontall yand vefitcally
//overflowing content will be clipped
//relative means child elements will be positioned relative to wrapper
const CenterContainer = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
    width: '98%',
    display: 'flex', //this ensures marginLeft: auto on right box pushes to right
    minHeight: '98%',
    height: '98%',
    margin: 'auto',
    marginTop: '4rem',
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    //if there isnt enough space, parent container forces horizonal scroll
  }));

  //this is immediate child of wrapper, contains right box
  //relative makes container point of ref to absolutely positioned children
  //overflowX: 'scroll' and overflowY: 'scroll': These styles force both horizontal and vertical scrollbars to appear if the content inside CenterContainer exceeds its boundaries.
  


// you can add styling on top of navbar to position it!


export default function LoginPage({children}) {

    const [ token, setToken ] = useState('');

    const [ activeButton, setActiveButton ] = useState('LOGIN') //default to log in

    const { isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector(state => state.auth);
    //useSelector is reading variable from reducer
    //we want to take these variables from redux state

const theme = useTheme();

  const {isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn} = useAuth();
  const {isProfileCreated} = useProfile();

  const [ success, setSuccess ] = useState(false);

  const [error, setError ] = useState(false);

  const [taken, setTaken] = useState(false);
  

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async (inputUsername, inputPassword) => {
    try {
        const loginDto = {
          username: inputUsername,
          password: inputPassword,
          // Include other registration data fields here
        };

      
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      };
  
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/login', loginDto, config);
  
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // Successful login
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        navigate('/');
        console.log('Login successful!');
      } else {
        // Handle login failure
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
        setError(true);
        console.error('Login failed.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle other errors
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
      setError(true);
      console.error('Error during login:', error);
    }
  };

  //if spring security session management exists in java backend, dont need to make front end handle sessions
  

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("submission"));  // Use event.currentTarget
    const inputUsername = formData.get("username");
    const inputPassword = formData.get("password");
    console.log("this is the formdata's username:" , inputUsername)
    console.log("formdata", Object.fromEntries(formData));



    if (activeButton === "LOGIN") {
        handleLogin(inputUsername, inputPassword);
    } else if (activeButton === "REGISTER") {
        handleRegister(inputUsername, inputPassword);
    }
};

const handleRegister = async (inputUsername, inputPassword) => {
  if (isLoggedIn === true ){
    console.log("Need to log out");
    return;
  }

  // Logic for registration
  try {
    const registrationDto = {
      username: inputUsername,
      password: inputPassword,
      // Include other registration data fields here
    };


    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Set the request header to JSON
      },
    };

    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/register', registrationDto, config);

    if (response.status === 200) {
      // Successful registration
      console.log('Registration successful!');
      setSuccess(true);
    } else {
      // Handle registration failure
      console.error('Registration failed.');
      setTaken(true);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle other errors
    console.error('Error during registration:', error);
  }
};


useEffect(() => { 

  console.log(isLoggedIn, "am i logged in");
  console.log(isProfileCreated, "do i have a profile created")
    
}, []);


  return (
    <motion.div
    initial={{opacity: 0}}
    animate={{opacity: 1}}
    exit={{opacity: 0, transition: {duration: 0.4}}}>
    <FullPageCenter>
    <Wrapper>
    <MainNavbar />
    {/* adding navbar above container so its rendered above containers... */}
    <CenterContainer>
      <LeftBox>
      { isLoggedIn===true &&
    <div sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100v' }}>
      <ItalicText style={{wordWrap:"break-word", overflowWrap: "break-word"}}>You are logged in!</ItalicText> 
      </div>
        }
        {
        (isLoggedIn !== true) &&
      <ItalicText style={{marginLeft: '6rem', wordWrap:"break-word", overflowWrap: "break-word", marginBottom: '5rem',marginTop: '0.7rem'}}>Log in to your account</ItalicText> 
        }
         
      </LeftBox>
        <RightBox justify="yes">
          {
            isLoggedIn!==true &&
            <Stack spacing="1rem" >
            <Box flexDirection="row" style={{ display: 'flex', width: '100%' }} justifyContent="space-between"> 
            {/* the space between is inside the parent stack */}
            <LogButton label="LOGIN" width='9rem' onClick={() => setActiveButton('LOGIN')} isActive={activeButton==='LOGIN'}/>
            <LogButton label="REGISTER" width='9rem' onClick={()=> setActiveButton('REGISTER')} isActive={activeButton==='REGISTER'}/>
            {/* i use isActive...boolean, if true then colors it blue */}
            </Box>
            {/* <Stack spacing="1rem"> don't need this stack */} 
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="submission">
            <InputField name="username" label="USERNAME" />
            <PasswordInputField name="password" label="PASSWORD" />
            <LogButton onClick={handleSubmit} label="submit" color="#000000" style={{flex:1}}/>
            </form>
             {/*the submit button fills the space in the flex component..the stack component   */}
            {/* </Stack> */}
            {/* <AuthContent />  */}
            
            </Stack>
}

{ isLoggedIn===true &&

<p>Time to go find your traitmate!</p>

}
            {error && 
            <SelectError message="Wrong login credentials. Try again?"></SelectError>
            }
            { 
            success &&
            <SelectSuccess message="Successfully registered! Now log in."></SelectSuccess>
}
{
  taken &&
  <SelectError message="The username is already taken! Try another"></SelectError>
}
        </RightBox>
    </CenterContainer>
    </Wrapper>
    </FullPageCenter>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

and MainPage.js:

```
import React from "react";
import MainHeader from "../components/MainHeader";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';
import MainNavbar from "../components/MainNavbar";
import { useAuth } from "../components/AuthContext";
import { useProfile } from "../components/ProfileContext";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const FullPageCenter = styled('div')({
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    minHeight: '100vh', // Set the minimum height to 100% of the viewport height
    //position: 'relative', //ensure relative positioning for stacking context
    backgroundImage: 'url("/MOONASSI_16_UNTITLED.png")', // <-- add this line
    backgroundSize: '800px',  // cover ensures the image fills the container without stretching
    backgroundPosition: '17rem bottom',  // center the image
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',  // don't repeat the image
    position: 'relative',
  });
  
  
  const Wrapper = styled('div')({
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      height: '45rem',
      width: '100%',
      overflowX: 'scroll',
      overflowY: 'scroll',
      marginBottom: '4rem',
      position: 'relative',
      // This is important for the absolute positioning of the child.
      
  });
  //this is to prevent resizing....
  
  
  //does putting position of top level copmonent as relative make all the child components, including grandchildren components, relative to the top level component? 
  
  //this is relative position only deals with direct children that are absolutely positioned
  
  //wrapper is outermost container...centers stuff in scree horizontall yand vefitcally
  //overflowing content will be clipped
  //relative means child elements will be positioned relative to wrapper
  const CenterContainer = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
      width: '100%',
      display: 'flex', //this ensures marginLeft: auto on right box pushes to right
      minHeight: '98%',
      height: '98%',
      marginTop: '2rem',
      border: '1px solid black',
      //if there isnt enough space, parent container forces horizonal scroll
    }));


  
  

function MainPage() {

  const {isLoggedIn} = useAuth();
  const {isProfileCreated} = useProfile();
  useEffect(() => { 

    console.log(isLoggedIn, "am i logged in");
    console.log(isProfileCreated, "do i have a profile created")
      
  }, []);
  return (
    <motion.div
    initial={{opacity: 0}}
    animate={{opacity: 1}}
    exit={{opacity: 0, transition: {duration: 0.8}}}>
    <FullPageCenter sx={{zIndex: -1000}}>
    <Wrapper> 
     <CenterContainer> 
    <MainNavbar sx={{zIndex: 9999 }} />
    <MainHeader/> 
    </CenterContainer>
    </Wrapper> 
    </FullPageCenter> 
   </motion.div>
  );
}


export default MainPage;
```

My navbar is also not receiving the isLoggedIn state update and is incorrectly rendering:

```
import React from "react";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, CssBaseline, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";
import { useProfile } from "./ProfileContext";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from "react";

const NavbarWrapper = styled('div')({
  width: '100vw',//adding this centers the navbar
  height: '4rem', // Set the height to 4rem 
  // Add any other styling you need for the navbar
  position: 'fixed',
  overflow: 'visible',
  zIndex: '1000',
  pointerEvents: 'auto', //set this to high value to make text hoverable in MyProfile.js
  // i think this overflow auto is what causes it to be fixed size
});

const NavbarAppBar = styled(AppBar)`
  background-color: transparent;
`;

const NavbarToolbar = styled(Toolbar)`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;


const NavbarNavlinks = styled.div`
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex: 1;
justify-content: space-between; /* Spread items evenly */
align-items: center;
margin: 10rem 10rem;
gap: 9rem;
pointer-events: 'auto';
`;

const NavbarLink = styled(Link)(({ theme }) => ({
  fontFamily: theme.typography.body2.fontFamily,
  fontWeight: 300,
  pointerEvents: 'auto',
  textDecoration: 'none',
  zIndex: 9999,
  color: 'black',
  '&:hover': {
      color: 'blue',
      borderBottom: '1px solid blue'
  }
}));

function MainNavbar() {
  const {isLoggedIn} = useAuth();
  const {isProfileCreated} =useProfile();

 useEffect(() => {

console.log(isLoggedIn, "am i logged in from navbar?");
 }
  , []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('MainNavbar re-rendered with isLoggedIn value:', isLoggedIn);
});


 

  // in styled, for font weight, remove the brackets
  
  return (
    <NavbarWrapper>
    <NavbarAppBar position="static" elevation={0} sx={{background: '#dfd3bc', maxHeight:'4rem',}}>
      {/* the sx prop has a higher specificity...easier to override styles */}
      <CssBaseline/>
      <NavbarToolbar>
      { (isLoggedIn===false || isLoggedIn===null) &&
        <NavbarNavlinks>
          <NavbarLink to="/login"><b>LOG IN</b></NavbarLink>
          <NavbarLink to="/"> <b>MAIN</b></NavbarLink>
          <a href="http://jasminenoodlewavey.vercel.app" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black'}}>ABOUT THE CREATOR</a>
        </NavbarNavlinks>
        }
        { isLoggedIn===true && isProfileCreated===false &&
        <NavbarNavlinks>
          <NavbarLink to="/logout"><b>LOG OUT</b></NavbarLink>
          <NavbarLink to="/create/1"> <b>CREATE PROFILE</b></NavbarLink>
          <a href="http://jasminenoodlewavey.vercel.app" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black'}}>ABOUT THE CREATOR</a>
        </NavbarNavlinks>
        }
        { isLoggedIn===true && isProfileCreated===true &&
        <NavbarNavlinks>
          <NavbarLink to="/logout"><b>LOG OUT</b></NavbarLink>
          <NavbarLink to="/myprofile"> <b>MY PROFILE</b></NavbarLink>
          <NavbarLink to="/match"> <b>FIND YOUR MATCH</b></NavbarLink>
          <a href="http://jasminenoodlewavey.vercel.app" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black'}}>ABOUT THE CREATOR</a>
        </NavbarNavlinks>
        }
      </NavbarToolbar>
    </NavbarAppBar>
    </NavbarWrapper>
  );
}

export default MainNavbar;
```

Is this an issue with my use of Navigation? Does my redirect from LoginPage.js to MainPage.js reset the useContext value? I'm unsure about how to proceed since I think I've implemented my AuthContext correctly....

Comment: Hey 'http://localhost:8080/auth/isloggedin' how this get api call make sure user is logged in. Because  you don't pass any info such as email or token in this call. Then how you checked it?